# Why is The size of Taskbar Icon of my Windows 10 Universal App built with Apache Cordova is Smaller than Other Apps

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Apache Cordova for making my UWP app. But the taskbar icon for my app is looking smaller than all other apps beside it.

[image]

The rightmost icon is showing for my app. As you can see it is smaller (looks like a padded version on all 4 sides) than all the other icons placed at the left of it.

This is the actual`Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png`, as you can see below, *there is no padding in my image*

[image]

I have followed Visual Studios' project template for Apache Cordova and here is my icon declaration in my `config.xml`

```
   <platform name="windows">
        <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
        <icon height="30" src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
        <icon height="310" src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="106" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
        <icon height="70" src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
        <icon height="170" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
        <icon height="44" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="71" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    </platform>
```

**Question**

How to make the icon of my app on the taskbar equal to all other icons present to the left of it.

Any idea?

Thanks.

**Edit After Issue Resolve**

Just wanted to share the fruit. *Thanks to @TruthSeeker my taskbar icon now looks like*,

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: i followed https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html#windows and for me it was working good. you can try..or if persist same error then try to set different random image icon for test..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing things directly to `project folder->platforms->windows->images` folder might work but I don't think that is a good idea. Rather we should put our image resources into `res` folder and let visual studio put things into correct places during `build`.

So, try these steps,

1. Create a 48px by 48px png version of your icon image
2. save it as **Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png** and **Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48_altform-unplated.png**
3. Copy both the files into `res\icons\windows` folder of your project
4. Now, time to edit the `config.xml` file

**Add the 2 files in your `config.xml`** (after whatever you have, it should work)

```
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png" target="Square44x44Logo"/>
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48_altform-unplated.png" target="Square44x44Logo" />
```

Now, build and run your app.

If still it doesn't work, empty the folder `project folder->platforms->windows->images` and then again run it. Now you will be able to see an unplated tile.

Hope it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me quite a bit of time. One note, the code has probably changed since this was originally posted but, as of Cordova 7.0.1 at the latest, a single <icon> element may be used in config.xml for a given base name and all variations will be copied, including the 'altform-unplated' variations.

Answer (score 1):

By default it's using a plated icon. You can create a unplated icon for windows platform by following steps:

1. Create a 48x48 icon image from your original image.
2. Copy it into two files: "Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png" and "Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48_altform-unplated.png".
3. Copy them to project folder->platforms->windows->images folder.
4. Run the app, you will see the change.

For details of icons on windows platform you can refer to this document:[Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets)

Comment: Not working :( I saw that url too... But there are No **"Scalable list assets Without plate"**... I am using visual studio's default template of config.xml and it has **Scale based Assets**, but not **Target-size based assets**

Comment: Hey, I guess I did something wrong previously. This method also works. But I also think that we should do our work in our working directory only i.e. `res` , and list the configurations in `config.xml`... (this method looks more like a hack, I love hacks though :D ) But thanks anyway for the answer.